# why the sql commands Interval is used for?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I wrote the following code in model with sql commands interval etc.

```
$i= $this->db->where('DATE_ADD(asl.search_run_date,INTERVAL 2 DAY) >', 'NOW()', FALSE);
```

I thought that `$i` consists of the records that are 2 days before the present date......i am i correct?why false is used in the above step?

Does the following step also does the same as above?

```
$where="(datediff(now(),asl.search_run_date) >= 1)";
```

Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 0):

Date_add(Now(), Interval 2 Day)
This adds two days to current date

Date_sub(Now(), Interval 2 day)
this subtracts two days from current date.

For Eg. You want to find records for last 1 month.
Use
Date_sub(now(), Interval 30 day);

Comment: Thank you priyanshu but what am i doing in my code i.e i put greater than now().Does it mean 5/11/2016 > today  'DATE_ADD(asl.search_run_date,INTERVAL 2 DAY) >', 'NOW()',